# error pushing to a remote branch previously created

Tags: git

I'm not an expert in git.

I've a repo online with master. I created a `dev` branch using `git checkout`.

Now I want to commit some local changes just to `dev` branch.

So i did.

```
git add file
```

Then

```
git commit -m "Dag acquisizione"
```

I got message

```
C:\Users\marco.fumagalli\GAIMPORT\dev>git commit -m "Dag acquisizione"
[origin/dev (root-commit) 8ed7bd4] Dag acquisizione
 1 files changed, 236 insertions(+)
```

Which seems ok to me.

Then if I do

```
git push -u origin dev
```

I got an error:

error: src refspec dev does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://marco.fumagalli@****/*/*/*****.git'

Comment: What is the output of `git branch`?

Comment: output is: origin/dev

Comment: And `git status`? It tells you on which branch you are. I suspect you are on a branch called `origin/dev`

Comment: yes it gives me origin/dev

Comment: Then I invite you to look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently on a branch named `origin/dev`, not `dev`. You probably created your branch with:

```
git checkout -b origin/dev
```

or something similar.

To fix it, first rename your branch to `dev`:

```
git checkout origin/dev # in case you are not on it already
git branch -m dev
```

then push it as you did:

```
git push -u origin dev
```

:+1: to you to use `-u` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created your branch on top of `master` branch of the repository.

```
 git checkout -b branch_name
 git add file1, file2 ...
 git commit -m "Suitable commit message"
 git push origin branch_name:branch_name
```

The last command will create a new remote branch with branch_name (if it doesn't exist) and push changes into that particular branch.